# Adding data to the database through the front-end in django

Tags: django

I am writing a small blog and I will like to have a page through which I will be updating the website without going to the admin panel but it seems am not getting something right. I've written a view function but it is not responding yet. Am getting an error saying: **The view music.views.upload didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**
Below is my models.py file

```
class UserUpload(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='', blank=True, unique=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=False)
    audio_file = models.FileField(default='')
    music_tag = models.ManyToManyField(MusicTag)
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    page_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    moderation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-uploaded_date']

    def save(self):
        self.uploaded_date = timezone.now()
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(UserUpload, self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.artist

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

This is my views.py file

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        AUDIO_FILE_TYPE = ['wav', 'mp3', 'ogg']
        IMAGE_FILE_TYPE = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']
        form = UserMusicForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.artist = request.POST.get('artist')
            form.title = request.POST.get('title')
            form.thumbnail = request.POST.FILES('thumbnail')
            form.audio_file = request.POST.FILES('audio_file')
            form.music_tag = request.POST.get('music_tag')
            messages.success(request, 'has been successfully uploaded')

            if form.thumbnail.url.split('.')[-1] not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPE:
                context = {
                    "form": form,
                    "message": "Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG"
                }
                return render(request, "music/upload1.html", context)

            if form.audio_file.url.split('.')[-1] not in AUDIO_FILE_TYPE:
                context = {
                    "form": form,
                    "message": "Audio file must be WAV, MP3, or OGG"
                }
                return render(request, "music/upload1.html", context)
            print("Remaining save")
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserMusicForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "title": "Upload Your Song",
        }
        return render(request, "music/upload1.html", context)
```

This is my html file

```
<div class="login-box">
    <h2>Upload Your Song</h2>
    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" name="artist" required="required">
            <label>Artist</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" name="title" required="">
            <label>Title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="file" name="thumbnail" required="">
            <label>Thumbnail</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="file" name="audio_file" required="">
            <label>Audio file</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" name="music_tag" required="">
            <label>Music tag</label>
        </div>
        <button style="background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Below is my form

```
class UserMusicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserUpload
        fields = ('artist', 'title', 'thumbnail', 'audio_file', 'music_tag')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an `else` statement for `if form.is_valid():`, causing the code to return nothing (`None`) when your form is invalid. You should return an error response in that case. You can access the errors using `Form.errors` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.error)).

Comment: Why is the form returning None? What am I not getting right

Comment: Because your form is invalid, which means that the data you send to the server is not correct according to the form. Either manually check the body that you are sending or use the error info as outlined in my answer to see what's wrong with the data.